# GraphQL type resolve field1 listRecords, field2 Quatity of Records

Tags: node.js, types, graphql

I'm trying to figure out how to solve a type definition like this:

```
const xType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'SysCountry',
    description: 'SysCountry API',
    fields: () => ({
        states: {
            type: new GraphQLList(sysCountryStateType),
            resolve(sysCountry) {
                const { _id } = sysCountry;
                return SysCountryStateModel.find({ sysCountryId: _id }).exec();
            }
        },
        statesQuantity: {
            type: GraphQLInt,
            resolve(sysCountry) {
                const { _id } = sysCountry;
                return SysCountryStateModel.count({ sysCountryId: _id }).exec();
            }
});
```

where the a field represents the list of records and the another one just the count of them. Is there a less consuming resources to avoid querying twice or more and solving that from a unique point ? Always returning a simple object (int in the case of quantity) and not one compound of several subfields including it (like returning both the list of fields and the quantity).

In other words, is there any way to solve statesQuantity without querying once again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming xType is a child, on your parent, obviously you are passing only the id field on xType, what you might want to consider is asynchronously fetch the data you need on the parent, IF on one request, it don't contain the data you need in a child, example:

```
// in this child, we destructure fields we need on the root, not {id}
const GraphQLChild = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Child',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('News'),
    userRate: {
      type: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'userRate',
        fields: {
          rate: {
            type: GraphQLInt,
            defaultValue: 0,
            resolve: ({rate}) => rate
          },
          important: {
            type: GraphQLBoolean,
            defaultValue: false,
            resolve: ({important}) => important
          },
          saved: {
            type: GraphQLBoolean,
            defaultValue: false,
            resolve: ({saved}) => saved
          }
        }
      }),
      resolve: ({userRate}) => userRate
    },
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: ({title}) => title
    },
}),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});
```

This is the parent where you would like to perform asynchronous fetch, IF in one request, it don't contain the data you need in child, so resolve an object that contains all the fields you want to resolve on the child:

```
const GraphQLParent = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Parent',
  fields: () => ({
    child: {
      type: GraphQLChild,
      resolve: async(root, args, context) => {
        const {childId} = root;
        const childData = await getChildTitle(childId).then(response => {
         const {title} = response.data;
         const userRate = await getChildUserRate(childId);
         return new xType({userRate: {...userRate}, title});
        })
      },
    }
  })
});
```

In a more complex scenario, consider using class constructors so it's easier to envision the fields of the object you want to create, in relay it's used to resolve object type by its' instance in nodeDefinitions, example:

```
class xType { 
  constructor({
    userRate,
    title
  }) {
    this.userRate = userRate;
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

so all the fetching happens on the parent, then you just resolve the fields on the child.

Comment: you mean in this case SysCountryStateModel should process the result